# Material UI's ClickAwayListener firing right away, which causes state to toggle twice

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, events, material-ui

I have been doing research on this for days and finally have decided to ask this on here. I am using react and material-ui's ClickAwayListener component. The idea is that I have a button, which toggles the this.state.showGridPopup to the opposite of whatever it is currently is. So if the user was to click it once, the grid popup should show, click it again, the popup should disappear. There is an `handleShowGrid` handler attached to the button that does this:

```
  handleShowGrid = (event) => {
    const { widgetButtonEl } = this.state;
    const element = widgetButtonEl === null ? event.currentTarget : null;
    console.log('In handleShowGrid!!!!!');
    this.setState({
      showWidget: !this.state.showWidget,
      widgetButtonEl: element
    });
  }
```

All this works well. And toggles the popup to show when we click on the button attached to the handler.

```
<ButtonBase onClick={this.handleShowGrid}>Open Swap</ButtonBase>
```

The issue is when I add Material-UI's ClickAwayListener. The reason for adding this is to close the grid when a user clicks outside the grid. Here is the ClickAwayListener below:

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleCloseWidget}>
   <SurveyGrid />
</ClickAwayListener>
```

And the handleCloseWidget handler:

```
  handleCloseGrid = (e) => {
    console.log('In handleCloseWidget!!!!!');
      this.setState({
        showWidget: !this.state.showWidget,
        widgetButtonEl: null
      });
  }
```

So now clicking outside grid is fine and closes the Grid. However, now, clicking on the button that should toggle the Grid being show (this.state.showWidget), causes the `handleCloseGrid` to fire. And then afterwards the `handleShowGrid` would fire. Is there anyway to not have the handleCloseGrid handler to fire? It seems like an issue with propagation and event bubbling. Have tried different things like `e.stopPropagation()` but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.